# Trigger Spring Configuration via Annotation in JEE Application

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, configuration

The war application uses JEE/CDI/JAX RS stack, managed by/deployed to Wildfly.

I want to simplify some parts of the app, for instance to let Spring handle configuration from properties file. So I need to combine JEE with Spring together.

Here is Spring Configuration:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
public class Config {

  @Value( "${hostName}" )
  private String hostName;

  public String getHostName() {
    return hostName;
  }
}
```

`Config` is injected via CDI annotion:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Consumer {

  @Inject
  Config config;

  public String test(){
    return "test +" + config.getHostName();
  }
}
```

`Config` is injected successfully, but its `getHostName` method returns always null. In Maven dependencies I've included `spring-core`, `spring-context`, `spring-beans` to the dependencies.

Now the `test.properties` file does not exist in the classpath.

How to trigger the file loading by Spring and throw an exception that a file does not exist. To make sure it works.

Comment: This won't work. You will need Spring to manage the injection and dependencies. Just adding those annotations and slapping in  few dependencies won't work.

Comment: If you want to read configuration frmo properties you may be able to use [microprofile config](https://microprofile.io/project/eclipse/microprofile-config). Or write a bean to read the configuration and expose the values via producer methods. Mixing Spring just for that is probably an overkill.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos, it is not an issue to write the bean that reads configuration. I planed to use Spring not only for configuration, but for some other things.  So original issue - mixing spring with jee, spring actually now also a provider of jee specs, Wildfly uses weld as provider for cdi. So I need a solution combine these contexts together.